# 14.10 Unity VNC to Android

Tags: unity, android, vnc

I'm trying to get a vnc session running so that I can show chrome on my android device. I've got two monitors connected to my machine, on one I'm programming, on the other I'm showing the website fullscreen and I want to use my phones screen to the phone version.

I have successfully connected from android to x11vnc. However that does not support extra sessions. I've looked into tightvncserver and vnc4server as per the links at the bottom of this post. Those did not help and are quite old.

Has anyone successfully done this, and if so, how?

*PS. Yes, I know I can navigate to the page from the network or emulate a phone screen in chrome developer tools, but that is not the goal.*

### I've tried:

[No desktop showing in Ubuntu 13.04 via VNC on a VPS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330983/no-desktop-showing-in-ubuntu-13-04-via-vnc-on-a-vps)
This gave me a blank grey screen with a mousepointer.
[How do you use an android tablet as a second display?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display)
This gave me a grey screen with a cross for a pointer. (I used the answer with seven votes).

Answer (score 0):

You've done it almost right with the second answer, need to fiddle a bit with the configuration file, try to use this:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus -n &
gnome-terminal &
```